# Populate data to listbox from SQL table using ASP calender as the trigger

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, listbox

I am using a asp calendar control and on selection change I am calling a sub.  I am trying to get info from sql using the start date of an event. All events with a start date from the users input date up to today's date will be shown. The sql qry works, been tested. But I can not get the info to populate in a listbox. Using the event name as the text and the ID as the value.

```
Protected Sub calendarChange(Source As Object, E As EventArgs)
        Dim startDate As Date = startCal.SelectedDate
        Dim adapter As New eVoteTableAdapters.ballotsTableAdapter()
        Dim ballotTable As eVote.ballotsDataTable
        ballotTable = adapter.GetBallotsByStartDateGetDataBy(startDate)
        ballotList.DataSource = ballotTable
        ballotList.DataTextField = "name"
        ballotList.DataValueField = "ballot_ID"
    End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add BallotList.DataBind(), otherwise it will remain empty